# Вывод одной и той же переменной JS в несколько div (в php foreach)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, foreach

Здравствуйте. Ломаю голову как вывести перемененную которая подсчитывается для каждого экземпляра foreach в php

Разработка ведется на laravel по этому используется синтаксис blade и хелперы из laravel

Пример кода.

```
{{ $items = App\Items::all() }}


@foreach($items as $item)
 <span>{{$item->title}}</span>
 <span>{{$item->content}}</span>
 <span id="price></span>
@endforeach


<script>
var minPrice = parseInt("{{ $item->start_price }}");
var maxPrice = parseInt("{{ $item->final_price }}");
var price = minPrice;
var delta = (maxPrice - minPrice) / 86400; //разница между начальной и конечной ценой разделенной на 24 часа в секундах

function setPrice() {
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
  price += delta;
  if (price > maxPrice)
    price = minPrice;
  price = Math.round(price * 100) / 100;
}

setPrice();
setInterval(setPrice, 1000);
```

Как правильно вывести переменную price для каждого экземпляра $items

Заранее благодарю !

Comment: очевидно надо внести код использующий $item внутрь foreach

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ. 
А в примере как это будет выглядить ?

Comment: так же берешь свой код и переносишь

Comment: JS может выводить только один id, по этому перенос здесь не поможет т.к будет повторятся один и тот же id несколько раз, а срабатывать будет только первый найденый

Comment: тогда разверни вопрос: что именно ты хочешь выводить, если ты сам говоришь - что выводишь только в один элемент :-)

Comment: Вопрос решил путем добавления $item->id к выводимому id 

<span id="price_{{$item->id}}"></span>

document.getElementById("price_"+post_id).innerHTML = price+post_id;